# Prove that $\Vert Av \Vert / \Vert Aw\Vert \le \sqrt{\kappa(A)}\frac{\Vert v \Vert_A}{\Vert w \Vert_A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Prove that

> $$\frac{ \Vert Av \Vert }{ \Vert Aw\Vert } \le \sqrt{\kappa(A)}\frac{\Vert v \Vert_A}{\Vert w \Vert_A}$$

Assuming that the matrix $A$ is positive definite so that it induce a norm for the vector. $\kappa(A)$ denotes the condition number of the matrix.

I had a go at it, but it’s not entirely obvious within my knowledge.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $\|v\|_A$?

Comment: $\Vert x \Vert_A^2 := \langle x, Ax\rangle$

Comment: The title and the body don't agree. But that aside: rewrite the left-hand side using inner products and think of $\kappa(A)$ in terms of singular values.

Comment: @prets typo fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of incuded 2-norm of matrices, assuming that $\lambda_1$ is the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix $A$, and $\lambda_n$ maximum, and the fact that matrix $A$ has factorization $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \lambda_1 \Vert x \Vert 
    &\le \Vert Ax\Vert 
    \le \lambda_2 \Vert x\Vert
    \\
    \sqrt{\lambda_1} \Vert x\Vert 
    & \le \Vert A^{1/2}x\Vert \le \sqrt{\lambda_n}\Vert x \Vert
    \\
    \implies
    \sqrt{\lambda_1} & \le \frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}x \Vert} 
    \le \sqrt{\lambda_n}
\end{aligned}
$$
Consider another vector then it also can be said that:

$$\sqrt{\lambda_1} \le \frac{\Vert Ay\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}y \Vert} \le \sqrt{\lambda_n}$$

So then:

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \sqrt{\lambda_1}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}x \Vert} 
    & \le \sqrt{\lambda_n}\sqrt{\lambda_1}
    \\
    \sqrt{\lambda_1}\sqrt{\lambda_n}& \ge \sqrt{\lambda_n} \frac{\Vert Ay\Vert}{\left\Vert
         A^{1/2}y
    \right\Vert}
    \\
    \implies 
    \sqrt{\lambda_1}\frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}x \Vert} & \le 
    \sqrt{\lambda_n} \frac{\Vert Ay\Vert}{\left\Vert
         A^{1/2}y
    \right\Vert}
    \\
    \frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}x\Vert} &\le \kappa(A) 
    \frac{\Vert Ay\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}y\Vert}
    \\
    \frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert Ay\Vert} &\le 
    \kappa(A) \frac{\Vert A^{1/2}x\Vert}{\Vert A^{1/2}y\Vert}
    \\
    \frac{\Vert Ax\Vert}{\Vert Ay\Vert} &\le 
    \kappa(A) \frac{\Vert x\Vert_A}{\Vert y\Vert_A}
\end{aligned}
$$
$\blacksquare$